# changing name legend matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, legend

In the following scatter plot

[image]

I would like to modify the legend in the following way:

cluster 2 (green) should become cluster 4 (green)
and cluster 4 (ligth blue) should become cluster2 (light blue)

IMPORTANT:

1) I would like to maintain the order in the legend (i.e. cluster 1 , cluster 2, cluster 3,etc.)

2) the colors in the plot should not change

is that possible using only the fig file? thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from the figure follow [these instructions](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100687).

To change the order in the legend you need to change the order in which you draw the clusters using `scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C)` - that is, switch between cluster2 and cluster4.

To keep the original colors in a different order you can do one of these:

- Set them manually: `C` is 'g' for green and 'c' for cyan (light blue), for example. Its all in the `scatter3` [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html). Note that this green is a different shade than the default second color. For the dark green used by default set `C = [0 0.5 0];`.
- Change the default color order. For switching 2 and 4 you can do:

  ```
  ColorOrder = get(gcf, 'DefaultAxesColorOrder');
  ColorOrder = ColorOrder([1 4 3 2 5:end], :);
  set(gcf, 'DefaultAxesColorOrder', ColorOrder);
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I cannot regenerate the figure since I've only the fig file...

Comment: I edited the answer to include this. You can also manually change such properties in the figure through Edit -> Axes Properties.